# Static IP on docker container not working

Tags: docker, networking

My ISP has given me a 10 IP addresses.  x.x.x.91-95 and x.x.x.161-165
I want to use 9 of them for my containers.

I have the host eth0 on x.x.x.91

So I did:
`docker network create --subnet x.x.x.0/24 --gateway x.x.x.254 mynet`

and then

`docker run -it --net mynet --ip x.x.x.165  ubuntu /bin/bash`

But I can't connect out

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:5b:cc:d2:a5  
          inet addr:x.x.x.165  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:504 (504.0 B)

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         x.x.x.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
x.x.x.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Any ideas?
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Comment: This question is more for https://serverfault.com . A [macvlan bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#macvlan-bridge-mode-example-usage) can assign network ip's to a container.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to the Macvlan driver (as suggested by Matt)
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/